# where to update rules, constrains and elements of xml schema

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to build my own xml schema.

For example, I have this element

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

where can I apply this schema? I mean  that I would like to have something (tool or website) where I can give the schema as input and then generates xml files to me. Plus, I would like to validate some xml files to a specific schema.

I have read the rules of asking question here and It seems that my question is off topic but it is not because I am asking a question about programming issue and I have tried to solve it but I couldn't because the xml schema in w3c is not that clear to me.

I appreciate your time and efforts to help me.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a sample XML with a schema using an online tool such as [this XML generator](http://xmlgrid.net/genXml.html). Once you have an instance, you can also validate it using online tools. [This XML validator](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) allows you to save the validation pair and refer to it later.

Before you attempt to generate or validate anything, you must have your schema properly constructed, with a `<schema>` root element and namespace declaration:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If you use the generation service mentioned above, you will obtain the following sample instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Document created with online XML Editor http://xmlgrid.net 2014/06/19 14:51:15  -->
<employee>
    <firstname>test string</firstname>
    <lastname>test string</lastname>
</employee>
```

You can also declaratively bind an instance to a schema so that it can be validated without having to specify the schema separately. If your schema has no target namespace you would use the XML Schema instance attribute `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` (which needs to be qualified in the XSD Instance namespace):

```
<employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema-uri.xsd">
    <firstname>test string</firstname>
    <lastname>test string</lastname>
</employee>
```

If it had a target namespace (which is *not* the case with the schema above), you would use `schemaLocation` which takes a pair (or more if you have elements from multiple schemas in one document) of space-separated strings which map the namespace and its location.

```
<employee xmlns="employee-namespace"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="employee-namespace schema-uri.xsd">
    <firstname>test string</firstname>
    <lastname>test string</lastname>
</employee>
```

For this to validate, your schema would need to have a `targetNamespace` attribute in the root element. Normally you would also declare the target namespace as the default namespace, sou you can *refer* to other local types if necessary:

```
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="employee-namespace"
            xmlns="employee-namespace"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```